# Imacros iimSet with Batch

Tags: firefox, batch-file, imacros

Is there any way to achieve set an Imacros variable with batch?

I would like to skip imacros browser from the task, also VBS is not a solution for me now.

This is what i have so far. It starts firefox then 10 seconds later the "test.iim"

```
start /B "" "firefox.exe"
timeout 10 >nul
start "" /w /b "firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m="test.iim"
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is maybe really complicated.

The possible way is combina .js script, batch file in following way.

The batch file would edit some .txt file and insert some values in it. The JS file would read those values and use iimSet to store them in iMacros code. It's a little complicated but could work.